# Unable to understand Constructor() syntax of a getter method in ns-3 source code

Tags: c++, ns-3

Below is the code snippet

```cpp
TypeId
UdpEchoClient::GetTypeId (void)
{
  static TypeId tid = TypeId ("ns3::UdpEchoClient")
    .SetParent<Application> ()
    .SetGroupName("Applications")
    .AddConstructor<UdpEchoClient> ()
    .AddAttribute ("MaxPackets", 
                   "The maximum number of packets the application will send",
                   UintegerValue (100),
                   MakeUintegerAccessor (&UdpEchoClient::m_count),
                   MakeUintegerChecker<uint32_t> ())
    .AddAttribute ("Interval", 
                   "The time to wait between packets",
                   TimeValue (Seconds (1.0)),
                   MakeTimeAccessor (&UdpEchoClient::m_interval),
                   MakeTimeChecker ())
    .AddAttribute ("RemoteAddress", 
                   "The destination Address of the outbound packets",
                   AddressValue (),
                   MakeAddressAccessor (&UdpEchoClient::m_peerAddress),
                   MakeAddressChecker ())
    .AddAttribute ("RemotePort", 
                   "The destination port of the outbound packets",
                   UintegerValue (0),
                   MakeUintegerAccessor (&UdpEchoClient::m_peerPort),
                   MakeUintegerChecker<uint16_t> ())
    .AddAttribute ("PacketSize", "Size of echo data in outbound packets",
                   UintegerValue (100),
                   MakeUintegerAccessor (&UdpEchoClient::SetDataSize,
                                         &UdpEchoClient::GetDataSize),
                   MakeUintegerChecker<uint32_t> ())
    .AddTraceSource ("Tx", "A new packet is created and is sent",
                     MakeTraceSourceAccessor (&UdpEchoClient::m_txTrace),
                     "ns3::Packet::TracedCallback")
    .AddTraceSource ("Rx", "A packet has been received",
                     MakeTraceSourceAccessor (&UdpEchoClient::m_rxTrace),
                     "ns3::Packet::TracedCallback")
    .AddTraceSource ("TxWithAddresses", "A new packet is created and is sent",
                     MakeTraceSourceAccessor (&UdpEchoClient::m_txTraceWithAddresses),
                     "ns3::Packet::TwoAddressTracedCallback")
    .AddTraceSource ("RxWithAddresses", "A packet has been received",
                     MakeTraceSourceAccessor (&UdpEchoClient::m_rxTraceWithAddresses),
                     "ns3::Packet::TwoAddressTracedCallback")
  ;
  return tid;
}
```

particularly this below segment

```cpp
static TypeId tid = TypeId ("ns3::UdpEchoClient")
    .SetParent<Application> ()
    .SetGroupName("Applications")
```

What is "Application" here in this SetParent() method?  The declaration of SetParent() is :

> TypeId SetParent (TypeId tid);
>   and
>   template <typename T>
>     TypeId SetParent (void);

Can somebody explain this GetTypeId(), what is going on here with nested dot(.) operators over a TypeId constructor?

Here is the link to files :
[1] https://github.com/signetlabdei/quic-ns-3/blob/master/src/applications/model/udp-echo-client.cc

[2] https://github.com/signetlabdei/quic-ns-3/blob/master/src/core/model/type-id.h

[3] https://github.com/signetlabdei/quic-ns-3/blob/master/src/core/model/type-id.cc

[4] https://github.com/signetlabdei/quic-ns-3/blob/master/src/applications/model/udp-echo-client.h

Comment: `a.b.c` means `.c` is applied to the result of `a.b`

Comment: @M.M thank you! but I meant to ask how these nested method calls are made when not declared explicitly in its header file, i.e. type-id.h?

Comment: Those functions certainly are declared somewhere. If you use an IDE it will take you to the declaration point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can somebody explain this GetTypeId(), what is going on here with nested dot(.) operators over a TypeId constructor?

If you look into the declaration of the symbols in the header file you'll notice that all those "nested dot operators" are just methods of the class `TypeId` returning a `TypeId`:

```
template <typename T> TypeId SetParent (void);
```

If you look into the source code of the method:

```
TypeId 
TypeId::SetParent (TypeId tid)
{
  NS_LOG_FUNCTION (this << tid.GetUid ());
  IidManager::Get ()->SetParent (m_tid, tid.m_tid);
  return *this; //here the copy takes place
}
```

it comes clear that it returns a copy of itself.

But why does it return a copy of itself? When looking into the header file again it comes clear that the struct TypeId just has one value it holds:

```
class TypeId
{
// lots and lots of method declarations
// [...]
/** The TypeId value. */ 
  uint16_t m_tid;
};
```

The copy is therefore just a tool to achieve the nesting of the operators.

So what does it do? As I haven't written this code I can't be 100% sure but for me it seems that it holds some meta information about passed types that you can change during runtime (e.g. change the constructor or the super class)

Comment: Thanks a lot @user3520616 for a clear explanation!  Can you explain this .SetParent<Application> (), what is <Application> in this context? Thank you again!

Comment: In `type-id.h` on line 645 there is the method that gets invoced, it seems to look up the TypeId of the given Type (`Application`) and than sets the parent via the `IidManager`. After that the `lidManager` is able to "make the connections" via its methods (e.g. "is type A the parent of type B?" which is not possible in c++ during runtime, this "faked inheritance" makes it possible however). Take a look at the `lidManager` it serves a central role here, the `TypeId` just holds the id of the type, the logic is in the `lidManager`.